# PHP str_replace or preg_match or strpos when specific string plus if integer

Tags: php, preg-match, str-replace, strpos

I am trying to remove the two strings and two integers from a URL string if there is a specific match, for example from those WP generated featured image crop URLS:

```
http://website.com/uploads/image1-150x150.jpg
http://website.com/uploads/image2-300x160.jpg
```

Basically I want to be left with:

```
http://website.com/uploads/image1.jpg
http://website.com/uploads/image2.jpg
```

I therefore need to check, if the URL has the order of a minus "-", then an INT, then the letter "x", then again an INT, before the .jpg ending. If so, then it should remove all of that.

What is the best way and how would I need to do it? preg_replace or str_replace or strpos?

Comment: Seems like a perfect fit for `preg_replace()`, why don't you want that answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace()` is the appropriate function for this.

```
$str = preg_replace('/-\d+x\d+\.jpg$/', '.jpg', $str);
```

Comment: What if the file is a png, or gif?

Comment: The question said _before the .jpg ending_. I took that liteally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/-[0-9]*x[0-9]*/", "", $link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace Regex:

```
/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+(\.[a-z][a-z][a-z])$/$1
```

You could even write it literally from your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+/
```

#### [Live Preview](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6Op)

```
//Input: http://website.com/uploads/image1-150x150.jpg
preg_replace("/-[0-9]+x[0-9]+/", "", $input_lines);
//Output: http://website.com/uploads/image1.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\\-\d+x\d+\\./', '.', $string);
```